# How to install 'alternatives' application on RHEL systems?

Tags: java, linux, rhel

I tried setting up new installed Java on RHEL 6.5 with '**alternatives**' application (as suggested in few websites) but seems 'alternatives' does not exist:

> alternatives

-bash: alternatives: command not found

Also not possible to install with YUM (can not find).
What is the way to install it properly on RHEL (I could not find direct link for download).

Comment: My bad - found it here: /usr/sbin/alternatives
Why is it not set by default to 'alias' name 'alternatives'?

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for the topics that can be asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: It seems there are a few questions related to this, including [Why Oracle java do not appears in the alternatives command on redhat 6.5?](http://superuser.com/questions/864135/why-oracle-java-do-not-appears-in-the-alternatives-command-on-redhat-6-5), hopefully they'll help you get it working